# Rock Paper Scissors Game Error, Javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, syntax, error-handling, syntax-error

I keep getting this error from the console:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'else' else if (choice2
>   === "paper") {

**This is my code**

```
var user = prompt("Rock, Paper, Scissors?");
var computer = Math.random();
if (computer < 0.34) {
    computer = "rock";
} else if (computer <= 0.67) {
    computer = "paper";
} else {
    computer = "scissors";
} console.log("computer: " + computer);

var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {

    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "Tie";
    }
else if (choice1 === "rock") {
    return "Rock wins";
}
else {
    return "paper wins";
}

}
else if (choice2 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
        return "paper wins";
    }
    else {
        return "scissors win";
    }
}
}
compare(user, computer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.

You end the compare function on line 25 or so and then start up another `else`. So that is not good, but it is just a duplicate curly brace, so when removing it we still get the error. This is because you are calling an `else if` after an `else`.

When we move the else to to under the `else if` and remove the duplicate curly brace, we get some code that actually runs

```
var user = prompt("Rock, Paper, Scissors?");
var computer = Math.random();
if (computer < 0.34) {
    computer = "rock";
} else if (computer <= 0.67) {
    computer = "paper";
} else {
    computer = "scissors";
}
console.log("computer: " + computer);

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {

    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "Tie";
    } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        return "Rock wins";
    } else if (choice2 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "paper wins";
        } else {
            return "scissors win";
        }
    } else {
        return "paper wins";
    } 
}
compare(user, computer);
```

Hope this helps. Also it makes it easier to debug (see the extra curly braces) when you use a tool to beautify your code a bit, I use -> http://jsbeautifier.org/